# Codeigniter- Blank row inserted into mysql even when the page loads or refreshes

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to insert some form data into mysql table in codeigniter. My problem is that,a blank row is inserted into the table before my actual data is inserted. Then I found that, even when the page loads or refreshes a blank row is getting inserted into mysql.

Here is my code:

controller:

```
class Amc extends MX_Controller {
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    // check if user logged in 
    if (!$this->ion_auth->logged_in())
    {
        redirect('module=auth&view=login');
    }
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('amc_model');

}
function addamc()
{
            $data = array('cust_id' => $this->input->post('customer_id'),
            'cust_name' => $this->input->post('cname'),
            'cust_address' => $this->input->post('addr'),
            'contact_person' => $this->input->post('contact_prsn'),
            'location' => $this->input->post('loc'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'prs' => $this->input->post('prs'),
            'rating' => $this->input->post('rating'),
            'hrs' => $this->input->post('hrs'),
            'engine_num' => $this->input->post('engine'),
            'model' => $this->input->post('model'),
            'amc_from' => $this->input->post('amcfrom'),
            'amc_to' => $this->input->post('amcto'),
            'expiry_date' => $this->input->post('expd'),
            'no_visit_agreed' => $this->input->post('visagree'),
            'no_visit_made' => $this->input->post('vismade'),
            'date_commence' => $this->input->post('doc'), 
            'last_oil_ser_date' => $this->input->post('losd'),
            'last_visit_date' => $this->input->post('lvd'),
            'visit_due' => $this->input->post('visitdue'),
            'visit_status' => $this->input->post('visitstatus'),
            'svc_status' => $this->input->post('svcstatus'),
            'amc_status' => $this->input->post('amcstat'),
            'actual_amt' => $this->input->post('actualamt'),
            'amt_recieved' => $this->input->post('amtrecieved'),
            'amt_due' => $this->input->post('amountdue'),
            'payment_method' => $this->input->post('paymentmethod'),
            'payment_due_date' => $this->input->post('paymentdue'),
            'assigned_to' => 'not assigned'
        );
    $this->amc_model->addamc($data);

    if ( $this->form_validation->run() == true &&$this->amc_model->addamc($data) )
    { 
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success_message', $this->lang->line('amc_added'));
        redirect("module=amc", 'refresh');
    }
}
```

model:

```
class Amc_model extends CI_Model
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

}
public function addamc($data = array())
{   
   $amcData = array(
                     'cust_id'  => $data['cust_id'],
                 'cust_name' => $data['cust_name'],
              'cust_address' => $data['cust_address'],  
              'contact_person' => $data['contact_person'],  
              'location' => $data['location'],  
              'email' => $data['email'],    
              'prs' => $data['prs'],    
              'rating' => $data['rating'],
              'hrs' => $data['hrs'],
              'engine_num' => $data['engine_num'],
              'model' => $data['model'],
              'amc_from' => $data['amc_from'],
              'amc_to' => $data['amc_to'],
              'expiry_date' => $data['expiry_date'],
              'no_visit_agreed' => $data['no_visit_agreed'],
              'no_visit_made' => $data['no_visit_made'],
              'date_commence' => $data['date_commence'],
              'last_oil_ser_date' => $data['last_oil_ser_date'],
              'last_visit_date' => $data['last_visit_date'],
              'visit_due' => $data['visit_due'],
              'visit_status' => $data['visit_status'],
              'svc_status' => $data['svc_status'],
              'amc_status' => $data['amc_status'],
              'actual_amt' => $data['actual_amt'],
              'amt_recieved' => $data['amt_recieved'],
              'amt_due' => $data['amt_due'],
              'payment_method' => $data['payment_method'],
              'payment_due_date' => $data['payment_due_date'],
              'assigned_to' => $data['assigned_to'] 
    );

    if($this->db->insert('amc_details', $amcData)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}   
}
```

View:

```
                    <?php $attrib = array('class' => 'form-horizontal'); echo form_open("module=amc&amp;view=addamc", $attrib);?>

                <table class="imagetable" align="center">
                <tr>
                <td width="180px" align="left" >Customer ID</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="customer_id" id="customer_id" /></td>
                <td align="center">Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="cname" id="cname" /></td>
                <td align="center">Address</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="addr" id="addr" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Location</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="loc" id="loc" /></td>
                <td align="center">Email ID</td>
                <td ><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
                <td align="center">Contact Person</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="contact_prsn" id="contact_prsn" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>ENGINE No</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="engine" id="engine" /></td>
                <td align="center">Model</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="model" id="model" /></td>
                <td align="center">PRS</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="prs" id="prs" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>Rating</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="rating" id="rating" /></td>
                <td align="center">HRS</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="hrs" id="hrs" /></td>
                <td align="center">Expiry Date</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="expd" id="expd" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="left">AMC From</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="amcfrom" id="amcfrom" /></td>
                <td align="center">AMC To</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="amcto" id="amcto" /></td>
                <td align="center">Date of Commencement</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="doc" id="doc" /></td>
                </tr>      <tr>
                <td align="left">No.of visit Agreed</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="visagree" id="visagree" /></td>
                <td align="center">No.of visit made</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="vismade" id="vismade" /></td>
                <td align="center">Last Oil Service Date</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="losd" id="losd" /></td>
                </tr> 
                <tr>

                <td align="left">Last Visit Date</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="lvd" id="lvd" /></td>
                <td align="center">Visit due every after</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="visitdue" id="visitdue" /></td>
                <td align="center">SVC Status</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="svcstatus" id="svcstatus" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="left">Visit Status</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="visitstatus" id="visitstatus" /></td>
                <td align="center">AMC Status</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="amcstat" id="amcstat" /></td>
                <td align="center">Actual Amount</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="actualamt" id="actualamt" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td align="left"> Amount Recieved</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="amtrecieved" id="amtrecieved" /></td>
                <td align="center">Amount Due</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="amountdue" id="amountdue" /></td>
                <td align="center">Payment Method</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="paymentmethod" id="paymentmethod" /></td>
                <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>

                <td align="left">Payment Due Date</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="paymentdue" id="paymentdue" /></td>

                <tr>
                <td>
                <?php echo form_submit('submit', $this->lang->line("submit"), 'class="btn btn-primary" style="padding: 6px 15px;"'); ?>      

                </tr>
                </tr>
                </table>


                <?php echo form_close();?>
```

I am a noob in codeigniter and I couldn't find whats wrong with the code. Can anyone please help me with this..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here in your controller you should call the insertion code only if the validation is true.

```
$this->amc_model->addamc($data);
```

Changes should be me made in the controller function addamc(). The final code will be

```
function addamc()
{
            $data = array('cust_id' => $this->input->post('customer_id'),
            'cust_name' => $this->input->post('cname'),
            'cust_address' => $this->input->post('addr'),
            'contact_person' => $this->input->post('contact_prsn'),
            'location' => $this->input->post('loc'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'prs' => $this->input->post('prs'),
            'rating' => $this->input->post('rating'),
            'hrs' => $this->input->post('hrs'),
            'engine_num' => $this->input->post('engine'),
            'model' => $this->input->post('model'),
            'amc_from' => $this->input->post('amcfrom'),
            'amc_to' => $this->input->post('amcto'),
            'expiry_date' => $this->input->post('expd'),
            'no_visit_agreed' => $this->input->post('visagree'),
            'no_visit_made' => $this->input->post('vismade'),
            'date_commence' => $this->input->post('doc'), 
            'last_oil_ser_date' => $this->input->post('losd'),
            'last_visit_date' => $this->input->post('lvd'),
            'visit_due' => $this->input->post('visitdue'),
            'visit_status' => $this->input->post('visitstatus'),
            'svc_status' => $this->input->post('svcstatus'),
            'amc_status' => $this->input->post('amcstat'),
            'actual_amt' => $this->input->post('actualamt'),
            'amt_recieved' => $this->input->post('amtrecieved'),
            'amt_due' => $this->input->post('amountdue'),
            'payment_method' => $this->input->post('paymentmethod'),
            'payment_due_date' => $this->input->post('paymentdue'),
            'assigned_to' => 'not assigned'
        );


        if ( $this->form_validation->run() == true)
        { 

           $result = $this->amc_model->addamc($data);

           if($result == true) {
              $this->session->set_flashdata('success_message', $this->lang->line('amc_added'));
              redirect("module=amc", 'refresh');
           } else {
              //insertion failed
           }
        }
}
```

Execution of the insertion statement must be done only if validations are true.

Comment: I've done as you said, Now when page loads or refreshes insertion is not happening. But even when I submit the form data, then also data is not getting inserted..

Comment: Try changing the 'form_open' format to form_open('amc/addamc', $attrib);

Comment: Try changing the code

echo form_open("module=amc&amp;view=addamc", $attrib); in view to 
echo form_open('amc/addamc', $attrib);  
Also please check whether validation works well.